# Toggle menu animation with on and off event handlers Jquery

Tags: jquery, animation

I am having trouble understanding the on() off() event handling logic.

My problem is trivial - I have a button that opens/closes menu and the menu itself. If the button is clicked again before the animation completes, I want it to stop the current animation slide back in. So far it either comes out and stays there or the animations are chained i.e. it ends up slid out twice as far.

My code:

```
<div class="menu-button"></div>
<div class="animate-menu"></div>
```

My Jquery code:

```
$('.menu-button').on('click', toggleMenu);

        function toggleMenu(e){

            var isMenuOpen = false;
            if(!isMenuOpen){
                $('.animate-menu').stop().animate({'right':'0'},300, function(){
                    isMenuOpen = true;
                });
            }
            else {
                $('.animate-menu').stop().animate({'right':'-200px'},300, function(){
                    isMenuOpen = false;
            });
        }
    }
```

Working jsfiddle example here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/npkrp1e0/2/)

I understand that I have to use on and off but I just have no idea how :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : You kept `var isMenuOpen = false` inside function and hence which will be always false every time function get called. Keep it outside function.

After completing animation you are changing the value of `isMenuOpen` hence when you want to stop animation for right sliding it will not get actual value of `isMenuOpen` and again going to `if` part instead of `else` part. So change `isMenuOpen` in first line of if / else part.

```
var isMenuOpen = false;
$('.menu-button').on('click',
        function (e){
            $('.animate-menu').stop();
            if(!isMenuOpen){
                isMenuOpen = true;
                $('.animate-menu').animate({'right':'0'},2000, function(){
                    
                });
            }
            else {
                isMenuOpen = false;
                $('.animate-menu').animate({'right':'-200px'},2000, function(){
            });
        }
    }
);
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/npkrp1e0/7/)**

**EDIT** - please not that I have increased transition time from 300 to 2000 to show effect. you can revert it to 300.

Comment: Thank you for the JQuery solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple code below:--
jQuery

```
$('.menu-button').click(function(){
    $('.animate-menu').toggleClass('opened');
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="menu-button">M</div>
<div class="animate-menu"></div>
```

Css

```
body{
    overflow-x:hidden;    
}
    .menu-button {
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        background: red;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
    }

.animate-menu {
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        background: red;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: -200px;
        transition:all 5s;
    }
.animate-menu.opened{
    right:0;
}
```

Check the live demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sarowerj/npkrp1e0/8/)

Comment: Thank you for an alternative solution!